# Java-stream to filter list?

Tags: java, java-stream

How to use the filter in java 8 stream to filter out complex List of objects.
Suppose I have a class like this

```
public class InfoLite{
    private String right;
    List<Others> options;
    private String new;
}
//getter,setter and constructor
```

```
public class Others{    
    private String workId;
    private String work;
}
//getter,setter and constructor
```

I have an info object which is similar to this

```
List<InfoLite> info = new ArrayList<>();
List<Others> options = new ArrayList<>();
options.add(new Others(1,"game"))
options.add(new Others(2,"unit"))
options.add(new Others(3,"dest"))
List<Others> options2 = new ArrayList<>();
options.add(new Others(1,"console"))
options.add(new Others(2,"unit"))
List<Others> options3 = new ArrayList<>();
options.add(new Others(1,"zan"))
options.add(new Others(2,"zebvra"))
List<Others> options4 = new ArrayList<>();
options.add(new Others(1,"zan"))
options.add(new Others(2,"lon"))
options.add(new Others(3,"car"))
info.add(new Test("game,unit",options,"Florida"));
info.add(new Test("console",options2,"Florida"));
info.add(new Test("zebvra",options3,"Florida"));
info.add(new Test("lon",options4,"Florida"));
```

Here how can I filter the `info` list so that I can get a new list like this

```
List<InfoLite> newInfo = new ArrayList<>();

List<Others> options = new ArrayList<>();
options.add(new Others(1,"game"))
options.add(new Others(2,"unit"))

List<Others> options2 = new ArrayList<>();
options.add(new Others(1,"console"))

List<Others> options3 = new ArrayList<>();
options.add(new Others(2,"zebvra"))

List<Others> options4 = new ArrayList<>();
options.add(new Others(2,"lon"))

info.add(new Test("game,unit",options,"Florida"));
info.add(new Test("console",options2,"Florida"));
info.add(new Test("zebvra",options3,"Florida"));
info.add(new Test("lon",options4,"Florida"));
```

Here `Others` object is basically filtered i.e. filter only those object from the `Others` list whose have the matching value from `right`  in `info`. If `right`  in `info` is a comma-separated then split the `right` and check-in each `Others` list  object and return the value.

What I tried is up to here but rest I am confused what to do next .

```
info.stream()
            .filter(option -> Arrays.stream(option.getRight().split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(option.getOptions().stream().filter(Others :: getWork))))``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you intend to print all `Others` instances that match one of the string in `right` value of `InfoLite`.

If that is the case the below snippet should help

```java
System.out.println(info.stream()
                       .flatMap(infoLite -> infoLite.getOptions()
                                                    .stream()
                                                    .filter(option -> Arrays.stream(infoLite.getRight()
                                                                                            .split(","))
                                                                            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                                                                            .contains(option.getWork())))
                       .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

**Output:**

```
[Others{workId=1, work='console'}, Others{workId=2, work='zebvra'}, Others{workId=1, work='game'}, Others{workId=2, work='unit'}, Others{workId=2, work='lon'}]
```

---

*Note:* I have made a couple of changes in the request program.

- In the below snippet

  ```
  List<Others> options2 = new ArrayList<>();
  options.add(new Others(1, "console"));
  ```

  It should have been `options2.add...`
- Assuming `Test` is a subclass of `InfoLite`
- Introduced `equals()` and `hashcode()` for `Others`.

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
      Others others = (Others) o;
      return workId == others.workId &&
            Objects.equals(work, others.work);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      return Objects.hash(workId, work);
  }
  ```

---

**UPDATE**
To retrieve the complete `InfoList` instances, the modified snippet is

```
info.forEach(infoLite -> {
    Set<String> rightSet = Arrays.stream(infoLite.getRight()
                                                 .split(","))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    infoLite.getOptions()
            .removeIf(option -> !rightSet.contains(option.getWork()));
});

info.forEach(System.out::println);
```

It produces the below output

```
InfoLite{right='game,unit', newString='Florida', options=[Others{workId=1, work='game'}, Others{workId=2, work='unit'}]}
InfoLite{right='console', newString='Florida', options=[Others{workId=1, work='console'}]}
InfoLite{right='zebvra', newString='Florida', options=[Others{workId=2, work='zebvra'}]}
InfoLite{right='lon', newString='Florida', options=[Others{workId=2, work='lon'}]}
```